# MongoDB Java driver @Discriminator @BsonDiscriminator annotations

Tags: java, mongodb

Mongo Docs http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/bson/pojos/ states:

> The easiest way to enable a discriminator is to annotate the abstract
>   class with the **Discriminator** annotation.

But the problem I see now, there is no **@Discriminator** annotation in 3.11 driver. I not sure is it the same as **@BsonDiscriminator**, which I can found at https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.11.0/org/bson/codecs/pojo/annotations/package-summary.html

How should I use **@Discriminator** and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a mistake in Mongo docs. I used **@BsonDiscriminator** and it works.

I was not able to find good example so I post here what I was implemented to check this. Please note I used Jackson but this is not shown in this answer. Thus some of annotations should be removed on **Parent**, **Pojo1**, **Pojo2**:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Pojo1.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Pojo2.class)})
@BsonDiscriminator
public abstract class Parent {

}
```

Child classes:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pojo1 extends Parent {
    String string;
    Integer number;
    Boolean flag;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Pojo2 extends Parent {
    String string;
    Integer number;
    Boolean flag;
}
```

Container class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Container {
    private String name;
    private List<Parent> pojos;
}
```

ContainerDAO persists and read container object which contains collection of Parent objects:

```
public class ContainerDAO {
    private static final MongoDatabase DATABASE = MongoDB.getDatabase();
    private static final MongoCollection<Container> CONTAINER_COLLECTION =
            DATABASE.getCollection("containers", Container.class);

    static {
        CONTAINER_COLLECTION.createIndex(
                Indexes.ascending("name"), new IndexOptions().unique(true));
    }

    public static void create(Container container){
        Bson filter =
                eq("name", container.getName());
        ReplaceOptions options = new ReplaceOptions().upsert(true);
        CONTAINER_COLLECTION.replaceOne(filter, container, options);
    }
    
    public static Container getByName(String name) {
        Container container = CONTAINER_COLLECTION.find(
                    eq("name", name))
                .first();
        return container;
    }

    public static void deleteOne(String name) {
        Bson filter =
                eq("name", name);
        CONTAINER_COLLECTION.deleteOne(filter);
    }
}
```

And the database connection object:

```
/**
 * MongoDb database and connection settings class
 */
public class MongoDB {

    private static final MongoDatabase DATABASE; 

    static {
        
        ...

        PojoCodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider
                .builder().register(com.researchforgood.survey.jackson.Parent.class, com.researchforgood.survey.jackson.Pojo1.class, com.researchforgood.survey.jackson.Pojo2.class).build();

        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider, PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build()));
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .codecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry)
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(settingsMap.get("url")))
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        DATABASE = mongoClient.getDatabase(settingsMap.get("database"));
    }
    
    public static MongoDatabase getDatabase() {
        return DATABASE;
    }

}
```

And here the test - an example of usage

```
@Test
public void saveAndRestorePojo() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ContainerDAO.create(container);

    Container containerFromDB = ContainerDAO.getByName(container.getName());
    LOG.info(containerFromDB.toString());

    assertEquals(containerFromDB.getPojos().get(0).getClass(), Pojo1.class);
    assertEquals(((Pojo1)containerFromDB.getPojos().get(0)).getString(), "Hello1!");
}
```

Comment: settingsMap is what?